# How can I add line-breaks the text on the individual ticks of an axes (D3.js)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an x-axis on my graph that plots the time by Day of the Month, Month, and 24hour time.

```
xScale = d3.time.scale()
     .range([margins.left, width - margins.right])
     .domain([new Date(this.startTime), new date(this.endTime)])
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(xScale)
     .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d %b %I:%M))
```

This produces ticks that have the time formatted like:

```
29 Dec 12:00
```

But what I want is

```
29 Dec
12:00
```

That is, a line break after the month. I need this because the text sometimes overlaps other text when it is all on one line. Is there any way to insert this line break?

I tried

```
d3.time.format("%d %b <br> %I:%M)
```

Which is obviously wrong. But that should make clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: this will helps http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Comment: Solution by the author of the thread marked by duplicate is more succinct. But thanks.